# time FE vs. individual FE vs. twoways FE

Tags: multiple-regression, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, finance

In my paper I want to know if there is correlation between sustainability and and the performance of a company. I want to explain the StockPrice with a lot of other variables and for sure the ESG-Score.

I created panel data and now I need to know wether I use the time FE, individual FE or twoways FE.

When I create the FE models the individual FE model is the only one which has a significant ESG-Score. The ESG-Score is very important to me so I thought let's use the individual FE-model, but doing the Hausmanntest it is loosing to the random effects model.

Later on I found out, that, ****surprise surprise**** you can't choose a model based on wether an variable that is important to you is significant or not.

So how do I decide which FE model I run against the random model?

Is there a test or something else that is answering that?

I also found the question ([Effects in panel models "individual", "time" or "twoways"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/effects-in-panel-models-individual-time-or-twoways)), but it's not really giving a final answer.

Fore sure I've been searching the internet twice, but I didn't found an answer specific for finance panel data, where you don't have things like gender that usually don' change over time.

I would be very greatful, if you could please help me. :)

Comment: I can give you a few links to papers in the past two years, but I am also a rookie and do not know how to realize it through software code, looking forward to expert advice. Paper 1: Fixed and random effects models: making an informed choice [Fixed and random effects models: making an informed choice](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-018-0802-x) Paper 2:Determining individual or time effects in panel data models [Determining individual or time effects in panel data models](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407619301861)

Comment: Thank you very much!